# JQgrid first row hight issue

Tags: jqgrid

Why my JQ grid 1st row or we can tell 0th row is increasing like this?
Why like this.. please find my code below.

[image]

```
 function bindGrid(jsondata)
 {
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid(
{
    //datatype: "json",
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    datastr: jsondata,
    colNames: ['username', 'email'],
    colModel: [
    {
        name: 'username',
        index: 'username',
        width: 100,
        classes: 'pointer'
    },
    {
        name: 'email',
        index: 'email',
        width: 250,
        classes: 'pointer',
        editable:true,        
        "editrules":{"required":true,"email":true}
    }
    ],
    //rowNum:10000,    
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: "Email Configuration",
    gridview: true,
    loadui: "block",

    rownumbers: true, //Displays Row number Column                       
    'cellEdit': true,
    'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray'
    ,editurl: 'clientArray'
    ,afterSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol)
    {debugger;
       var username =$('#list1').jqGrid ('getCell', rowid, 'username');
       var email =value;
       UpdateEmailInDataBase(username,email);
    },
    shrinkToFit:true,
    height: "100%",
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[5,10,20],
    pager: '#pager',
    ignoreCase:true,
    viewrecords: true        
}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you placed the grid inside of some div with `float: left` of `float: right` CSS style. You can try to move the `<table id="list1"></table><div id="pager"></div>` *temporary* as the first direct child of `<body>` to verify this. It's good to examine (to trace) the styles of the first row (which has too large height value). One can use Developer Tools of IE (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start and then go in Find menu), Chrome or Firefox to examine the CSS styles applied.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, your view helped me. The issue is with height

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oleg, your view helped me.
  The issue is with height

```
<input type="button" value="Load" id="btn" />
<div>
    <table id="list1" height="700px">
    </table>
    <div id="pager">
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed the height and its working fine